# Clang-format: how to format C struct initializer this way

Tags: c, struct, initializer, clang-format

I'm using the linux kernel .clang-format as a reference, but this part is bothering me.

How can I get clang-format to format this code

```
const struct my_struct hello = {.id = 0,
                                .modsmin = 10,
                                .modsmax = 20,
                                .strengthmin = 0,
                                .strengthmax = 100,
                                .color = COLOR_FOREGROUND };
```

to this

```
const struct my_struct hello = {
    .id = 0,
    .modsmin = 10,
    .modsmax = 20,
    .strengthmin = 0,
    .strengthmax = 100,
    .color = COLOR_FOREGROUND
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), there don't seem to be any `clang-format` style options which will do what you want.

But, you can use the "comma-after-last-item" trick. Put a comma after the last designated initializer, before the final closing brace. I believe this is still valid C code. Then `clang-format` will put each initializer on a separate line, and this will move the indentation back to what you're looking for. So the output would look like this:

```
const struct my_struct hello = {
    .id = 0,
    .modsmin = 10,
    .modsmax = 20,
    .strengthmin = 0,
    .strengthmax = 100,
    .color = COLOR_FOREGROUND,
};
```

This behavior is not documented anywhere (as far as I know), so I suppose it could be changed in the future. But this behavior has been there for many years and many versions of `clang-format` so I think it is reasonable to rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding the following to my .clang-format:

```
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
```

In the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#cpp11bracedliststyle) it's said that if this parameter is `true`, there is "No line break before the closing brace".

If this option must be set to `true`, then other tricks, like putting `,` or `//` before closing brace would still suffice.